# list of gentoo binary packages

Tags: binary, gentoo

Installing gentoo in my old laptop is a painful work, as the weekly update can make the poor cpu extra hot.

To stick into gentoo with less emerge effort, I decided to use binary files for large packages e.g., chrome, firefox, libreoffice ect.

Just wondering if there is a list of packages that provides binary ebuilds in the repo, so that I can quickly identify these package and swap them into binary ones?

Comment: I think most of the ebuilds that install precompiled binaries have something like `-bin` in their names, so a search for that with something like `$ eix -- -bin` might get you part way there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`eix *-bin` will give you all the bin packages in `portage`.  There is also [`PORTAGE_BINHOST`](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Binary_package_guide), which is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: The *-bin package is in fact more than 50 where eix is able to display once. to enable eix display more than 50, I have to add **EIX_LIMIT=0** in **~/.eixrc** file.

Comment: You don't need eix - just `find /usr/portage/ -type d -a -iname "*-bin" | sort`. `PORTAGE_BINHOST` is only helpful if you have a binary package host set up. I don't know of any public ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different machine, you could prebuild binary packages for the laptop and just merge it there. Another alternative would be icecream or distcc for offloading the work to a different box which does the compile for you.